# How to use REGEXP_LIKE in trigger's When condition?

Tags: regex, plsql, triggers

```
create or replace trigger emp_trig  
before  insert or update of salary on emp  
for each row  
when `REGEXP_LIKE(:new.job_id, 'ac*','i')` -- Here

    BEGIN
        IF inserting then
            :new.commission_pct := 0.20;
        elsif  (:old.commission_pct is null) then
            :new.commission_pct := 0.1;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: Please use code formatting when asking a question -- it makes it much clearer for people to quickly see and understand your code and problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace trigger emp_trig
before  insert or update of salary on emp
for each row
when (REGEXP_LIKE(new.job_id, 'ac*','i'))
BEGIN
IF inserting then
    :new.commission_pct := 0.20;
elsif  (:old.commission_pct is null) then
    :new.commission_pct := 0.1;
END IF;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey. if you are trying to do a simple match then avoid using Regular
>   expression. Instead go with LIKE and your test condition. Below
>   snippet illustrates a simple example to suffice your requirement. Hope
>   it helps

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER emp_trig before
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE OF sal ON emp FOR EACH row 
  WHEN (new.job LIKE '%TEST%')
  DECLARE
    BEGIN 
    IF inserting THEN 
    :new.comm := 0.20;
    elsif (:old.comm                      IS NULL) THEN
    :new.comm                           := 0.1;
    END IF;
    END;
```